# Running npm `postinstall` script after the original `npm install` finishes? (Maybe by using a Node trick?)

Tags: node.js, npm

I'm trying to create an npm module that has a `postinstall` script that will modify the user's `package.json` and re-install packages. I'm almost there, but the problem I'm having is that the npm CLI runs my `postinstall` script too early.

Is there a way, maybe by using Node or system level trick, to wait for the whole `npm install` process to exit before my script runs? Like when npm calls my `postinstall` script, at that time I can register another script to run after `npm install` finishes?

What do I mean by "too early"? For example, after `yarn install`, the `yarn.lock` file will not accurately reflect the `package.json` if my script interferes with `yarn install`. However, if my script waits for `yarn install` to completely finish and then runs another `yarn install`, the `yarn.lock` file will be accurate and further `yarn install` commands will output "Already up-to-date".

Comment: Ask the user to run a script which first invokes `npm install` and then calls your `postInstall` script?

Comment: @Safi can you post your package.json

Comment: @KalanaDemel This is the latest one with has the changes that jervtub suggested https://unpkg.com/commonpkg@1.0.77/package.json

Comment: what's your npm and node versions ?

Comment: @KalanaDemel npm 4.5.0 and Node 6.10.2.

Comment: I think you might more likely be looking for *hook scripts*; see https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#hook-scripts

Comment: So if I understand correctly, you want to use package.json to update "itself" and then run itself again? (No pun intended)

Comment: Ps. I would go nuts if I install a npm package and it would edit my package.json. That thing is sacred, you can't just mess around in there.

Comment: @stevenvanc It would not modify your `package.json` unless you went through the trouble of configuring your `package.json` specifically to work with this package, which you wouldn't do unless you've understood how the package works.

Comment: @M.K.Safi did you find a solution to this?, I have the same requirement, please let me know

Comment: @Teebo Nope, wasn't able to find a solution. Ended up following a completely different approach to achieve my goal.

Comment: @M.K.Safi cool, I also did figure out something thanks

Answer (score 5):

Considering tampering directly with the *package.json* is bad practice, because Devs will no longer be in control of the packages they have installed, or even their project name.

Therefore, packages should instead request the Dev to change the *package.json* during installation and offer a method to enable Devs for a *dry-run* of the  changes that will be made.

**TLDR**; make sure to give full consent to the Dev for any tampering of the *package.json*.

That's why I think alternative methods are better than using a postinstall script. The most minimal solution I have come up with:

**myinstall.js**

```
const exec = require('child_process').exec;
exec('npm run install').on('exit', () => exec('npm run mypostinstall'));
```

**package.json**

```
"scripts": {
  "myinstall": "node myinstall.js",
  "mypostinstall": "echo \"myPostinstall called\""
},
```

Set the `mypostinstall` script equal to the `postinstall`.

Note: in the example above there is no error handling, no text is displayed and there is no actual write to the *package.json*. It is pure for illustration on how to do execute code after `npm install`. The reason no text is being displayed is due calling `exec`, for which a new process is called with it's "personal" *stdout*. Alternatively use `fork`, more info can be found [here](https://nodejs.org/dist/latest-v6.x/docs/api/child_process.html) at the node documentation.

I have attempted to call `npm install` instead of `npm run myinstall` by setting 
`"install": "node myinstall.js"`. However now the `exec('npm run install')`will recursively call itself.

Comment: Thanks @jervtub, but I would like this to work with the plain `npm install` or `yarn install`. I don't want to ask the user to run an alternative command. The way I've dealt with the recursive call is by doing `myInstall=attempted npm install` and when the `myInstall` env variable is present, I don't call `npm install` recursively. If we do something similar with your solution, can we make a script that runs after the user-initiated plain `npm install` has fully completed?

Comment: I've tried your solution [here](https://github.com/hollowverse/commonpkg/blob/process-exit-implementation/src/index.ts), it doesn't seem to work

Comment: There shouldn't be a `postinstall` script, since npm will call this script automatically while we want to call our script manually. For​ instance, rename `postinstall` to `mypostinstall`. Also, don't forget to call `npm run mypostinstall` when the `myInstall` env is present.

Comment: I don't want the script to be called manually. Like I said, when the user installs my package on their application, I want the script to run automatically when the 'npm install' command completes.

Comment: So, when the user only runs `yarn add commonpkg`, afterwards code must be executed?

Comment: Yes. But the main way I'm testing it is by already having `commonpkg` in `devDependencies` of the user. Now the user does `yarn install` in their package, and that's the command after which I want my `postinstall` script to run.

Comment: @M.K.Safi You'd be surprised to know that this is still an issue but there's no solution. How did you mange to do it?

Answer (score 0):

`postInstall` as you have found out has very unusual way of execution and bugged in some versions of npm (all pre npm 3) , This was fixed in the later versions So first of all make sure your npm version is up to date; If it is you have 2 options that I can give you off the top of my head,

**Option 1**

This is the most simplest solution, use this script, it's pretty self explanatory it will install everything and to be on the safe side give the post install a once over. Not the most ideal solution but it should work without issues.

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install
npm run postinstall
```

**Option 2**

Try moving your `devDependencies` to `dependencies` if possible, for some users this seem to fix the `postInstall` issue. But I don't recommend it `devDependencies` are there for a reason.

**UPDATE**

Ok, I get the issue now, but it should be covered with a slight variation to the option 1's script. Since your postinstall script can already handle the  modification and re-installation.

```
#!/bin/bash
npm install
cd (<path to your module> && npm run postinstall)
```

Comment: I want the `postinstall` script of my module to run when a user install my package. It's not for my own package.

Comment: I want my post install script to run when a user has my package as a dependency and the user does 'npm install' in their package. And I want the post install script to run after the user's 'npm install' completely finishes

Comment: That's what this script does, the first npm install will first install everything, and fail to run your postinstall properly as intended. Then the second line will go to where your module is located in the node_modules folder and run the postinstall of the packge.json of that module, oh you can add another npm install after if it's not in your postinstall script. Or am I missing some thing here, btw npm install probably would not be able to make it work, since what you plan to do is not exactly intended usage, your best solution would be to run it as a script.